# yii functional test with authenticated user

Tags: php, authentication, yii, functional-testing

I am tryinng to run a functional test with an authenticated user on YII with selenium.
I wrote the following

```
protected function _login(){

    $id=new UserIdentity('admin','admin');
    $id->authenticate();
    if($id->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        Yii::app()->user->login($id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public function testSpot(){
    $this->assertTrue($this->_login());
    ob_end_flush();
    $this->open('production/request/create');
}
```

I added an ob_start() on bootstrap.php because the header were being sent twice and flushed it after the login.Still the test when access production/request/create goes to the login page, because the login is not computed even though it's valid.

EDIT:
the ob_end_flush and ob_start is not needed if you use --stderr option on phpunit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont work because you are only authenticating against the session that is running from the command line. You need to authenticate the web session.

See this comment:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional#c10015